# How remove variations in a time series X caused by another time series Y?

Tags: time-series, correlation, variance, seasonality

I have a time series on a monthly basis (a commodity) of which much variation is caused by the weather. I want to adjust this commodity  for weather changes. 
I use Heating degree day as a proxy for the weather conditions (If the average temperature of one day is below a threshold value, the absolute value of the difference is the heating degree for one day. This is summed up for all days in a month.)

Important: I already adjusted for the series for seasonality.

How should I proceed?